# Loading Components/Classes into an ArrayList via some component Name Pattern

Tags: java, spring, singleton, components, classloader

I have a number of classes of the same type (`com.project.abc.abs.Agent`) annotated like so;

`@Component("WEB.Agent-1"), @Component("WEB.Agent-2"), @Component("WEB.Agent-3")`... etc. For now assume that all classes are in the same package (`com.project.abc.web.Agent1...`).

These classes are all singletons, and I want to load them dynamically into a central 'Agent manager' class. I.e. every time a new agent class is added with the `@Component("WEB.Agent-#")` annotation it is picked up without having to make changes to the Agent Manager. In the AgentManager class I need some method to load any component that matches the name "WEB.Agent-#" (where # is a number or some unique ID) is this possible using any methods in Spring?

If not I'm assuming that I would need to go about loading all classes from a particular folder/package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) and add an exclude filter that gets rid of things that don't match your pattern:

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
    new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider();

scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Component.class));
scanner.addExcludeFilter(new TypeFilter(){
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, 
                         MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory){
        return metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata()
                 .getAnnotationAttributes(Component.class.getName())
                 .get("value").matches("WEB.Agent-[0-9]+");
    }
});

for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.project.abc.web.Agent1"))
    System.out.println(bd.getBeanClassName());
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, it would appear that `.getAnnotationAttributes()` requires a String argument, should this be a `.getAnnotationAttributes("Component")`?

Comment: When running throug the for loop I get the error  `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file`

Comment: @NightWolf, I think you need to specify `Component.class.getName()` (the fully qualified type name).